# Почему в C++ при сдвиге не получается ноль?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, битовые-операции

```
(uint64_t)1 << (size- (size - 1) / 64*64)   1   unsigned __int64
((uint64_t)1 <<64)                          0   unsigned __int64 
(size- (size - 1) / 64*64)                  64  int
int size=128;
```

Почему первое выражение не 0?

*Visual C++ 2017*

Comment: А чему равно `size`?

Comment: int size = 128;

Comment: https://ideone.com/9IyUFS - почему не ноль? ноль...

Comment: Visual C++ 2017 у меня это не 0

Comment: У вас величина сдвига == 64, т.е. 6 младших (значащих для сдвига 64-бит целого) разрядов == 0. Вот и получится 1 (то же самое, что `1 << 0`) / (По правилам (стандартам) языка такой сдвиг, наверняка UB, но по жизни, современные процы обычно просто отбрасывают ненужные разряды в регистре)

Comment: Забавно, что если в VC++ включить полную оптимизацию - получим 0; не включить - 1.

Comment: У меня 0 получаеться

Comment: Вероятно, компилятор с оптимизацией производит вычисления во время компиляции и "понимает", что `1 << 64` все же 0 (для 64-бит переменной) (да, "по человечески" это абсолютно верно)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из стандарта ([[expr.shift]p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.shift#1)) об `<<`:

> Если правый операнд отрицательный либо его значение больше или равно длине (в битах) левого операнда после расширения, то поведение программы не определено.

```
128-(128-1)/64*64 = 64
```

Т.е. равно длине левого операнда - так что поведение не определено...

Comment: Я поправил, т.к. очень сложно находить по номеру главы. Лучше по её идентификатору ссылаться. Нумерация постоянно меняется.

Comment: @ixSci Нет вопросов. Просто у меня книга *Стандарт С++: перевод, комментарии, примеры* Зуева и Чупринова, а в ней только номера глав...